# Planet texture generator

Tags: texturing, materials, compositing-nodes

What cross-platform (or cross-browser) resources are available to help make texture maps for generating  [beautiful](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NbCr0UyoFJA) planetary [images](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VGvnJDRr6HI) using Blender (Cycles)? Ideally, these would include:

- Terrain maps (colour, land, ocean, lakes, rivers, mountains, etc.)
- Height maps (normal and bump)
- Specular masks (land mask)
- Cloud maps
- Gas giants

Answer (score 53, accepted):

## Custom Texture Map Generators

Software to help generate planetary texture maps.

- [Rye Terrell's texture map generator](http://wwwtyro.github.io/procedural.js/planet1/)
- [Planet generator](http://topps.diku.dk/torbenm/maps.msp)
- [TerraNoise](http://www.guruware.at/main/terraNoise/index.html)
- [PlanetMaker](http://planetmaker.wthr.us/)
- [Sci-Fi World Generator](http://donjon.bin.sh/scifi/world/) (Map Palette option has a land mask)
- [Experilous Planet Generator](https://experilous.com/1/planet-generator/2015-04-07/version-2)
- [Cloud Maps](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/35724/how-can-i-easily-create-cloud-texture-maps)
- [Fracplanet](http://www.bottlenose.net/share/fracplanet/)
- [Terraform](http://www.firedrake.org/terraform/) (X11)

### Java

- [TerraJ](http://terraj.sourceforge.net/renders.html)
- [Planet Genesis](http://sourceforge.net/projects/planetgenesis/) ([website](http://planetgenesis.sourceforge.net/))

### Unavailable

Software that is offline, defunct, unreleased, or otherwise unavailable but still potentially useful.

- [Fractal Worldmap Generator](http://www.lysator.liu.se/~johol/fwmg/fwmg.html) (defunct)
- [Scientific Exoplanets Renderer](http://phl.upr.edu/projects/ser) (unreleased)

### Source Code

Links to uncompiled software.

- [Planet generator](http://www.diku.dk/~torbenm/Planet/) ([mirror 2](https://github.com/SakyaStelios/TorbenMaps))
- [Planet generator](https://github.com/jpbetz/planet-generator)
- http://www.oocities.org/area51/6902/t_torben.html (Java version of Torben's code)
- https://github.com/unconed/NFSpace
- https://github.com/fluffyfreak/GLSLPlanet
- [Fracplanet](https://github.com/ldo/fracplanet)
- [Fractal Worldmap Generator](http://www.lysator.liu.se/~johol/fwmg/source/worldgen.c)

## Free Maps

Maps of various resolutions (often without specular, cloud, or normal maps).

- [Extraterrestrial Planetary Surface Texture's for Imaging Professionals](http://freebitmaps.blogspot.ca/)
- [Flatplanet](http://flatplanet.sourceforge.net/maps/alien.html)
- [Planet Texture Maps 01](http://hameed.deviantart.com/art/Planet-texture-maps-01-116701701) (by Hameed)
- [Pix For Planet Texture Maps](http://pixshark.com/planet-texture-map.htm) (various, license unknown)
- [Deep Time Maps](http://deeptimemaps.com/map-lists/)
- [Maps of Fictional Worlds](https://sites.google.com/site/mapsandsuch/maps-of-fictional-worlds)

### Solar System

- [NASA Images and Textures](http://nasa3d.arc.nasa.gov/images)
- [Planetary Pixel Emporium](http://planetpixelemporium.com/planets.html)
- [JPL/Cassini Saturn's Moons](http://www.jpl.nasa.gov/spaceimages/details.php?id=PIA18439)

## Tutorials

Comprehensive web pages that describe various ways to craft realistic texture maps.

- [Making Worlds](http://acko.net/blog/making-worlds-introduction/) (C++)
- http://xnameetingpoint.weebly.com/planets1.html
- [libnoise](http://libnoise.sourceforge.net/tutorials/tutorial8.html) (how to use the API)
- [Using "Planet" for 16-bit maps](https://astrographer.wordpress.com/2013/02/06/using-planet-for-16-bit-planetary-maps/)
- [Orthographic projection of 2D SVG texture map onto 3D SVG sphere](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/128396/4902)

### GIMP

- [Creating Normal Maps](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KT4z8J9A87o)
- [GIMP Planet Making](http://jesterraiin.dropmark.com/170117/3639588)

### Photoshop

- [Create Planets in Photoshop](http://thegreystudios.com/blog/?p=93)

## Binaries

Binaries that run under Windows and Wine.

- [Planet Editor](http://orbithangar.com/searchid.php?ID=2542)
- [Wilbur](http://www.fracterra.com/wilbur.html) (run `winetricks vcrun2010` to install missing DLLs)

## Related

Related information about planetary texture maps.

- [Rules Can Be Beautiful](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GEVutbSqBI0&t=445) (TEDx Talk, jump to 7m 30s)
- [Procedural Planets, Heightmaps and Textures](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/5141/15700)

### Research, Whitepapers

- [Height Maps, Cube Maps, etc.](http://www.andrewwillmott.com/tech-notes)
- [Planet Map Generation by Tetrahedral Subdivision](http://curis.ku.dk/ws/files/17117759/planetPSI.pdf)
- [Procedural generation and realtime rendering of planetary bodies](http://cgg.mff.cuni.cz/~kahoun/files/kahoun_martin_bachelor_thesis.pdf)
- [Planetary Scale Terrain Composition](http://csc.lsu.edu/~kooima/pdfs/Kooima-Dissertation.pdf)

## Palettes

Cartography palettes for planetary colours.

- [Standard Color Palettes for Relief Maps](http://www.geos.ed.ac.uk/it/howto/GMT/CPT/palettes.html)
- [Archive of colour gradients](http://soliton.vm.bytemark.co.uk/pub/cpt-city/)

*[Long Live the Rainbow](https://mycarta.wordpress.com/2012/12/06/the-rainbow-is-deadlong-live-the-rainbow-part-5-cie-lab-linear-l-rainbow/)*
[image: Rainbow]

*[Creating beautiful relief models](https://whiteboxgeospatial.wordpress.com/tag/hillshading/)*
[image: Hillside Relief]

*[Best Colour for Elevation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25099/what-is-the-best-colour-ramp-to-use-for-elevation/109969#109969) (no snow)*
[image: Elevation - No Snow]

*[Best Colour for Elevation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25099/what-is-the-best-colour-ramp-to-use-for-elevation/109969#109969) (with snow)*
[image: Elevation - Snow]

*[ESRI Mapping Center](http://mappingcenter.esri.com/index.cfm?fa=arcgisResources.gateway)*
[image: Bathymetry and Elevation]

[image: ESRI Hyposemetry Color Ramps]

### Red, Blue, Green

Palettes given as red, green, blue values.

#### Snowball colors

```
Palette {
  Class          "IceWorld"
  StyleRange     (0.00, 0.00)
  colorSea       (1.00, 1.00, 1.00, 0.50)
  colorShelf     (0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 0.50)
  colorBeach     (0.80, 0.80, 0.80, 0.75)
  colorDesert    (0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 1.00)
  colorLowland   (0.87, 0.87, 0.87, 1.00)
  colorUpland    (0.93, 0.93, 0.93, 1.00)
  colorRock      (1.00, 1.00, 1.00, 1.00)
  colorSnow      (1.00, 1.00, 1.00, 1.00)
}
```

#### White-brown colors

```
Palette {
  Class          "IceWorld"
  StyleRange     (0.00, 0.00)
  colorSea       (0.30, 0.25, 0.22, 0.00)
  colorShelf     (0.37, 0.31, 0.28, 0.00)
  colorBeach     (0.56, 0.47, 0.42, 0.20)
  colorDesert    (0.70, 0.70, 0.70, 0.50)
  colorLowland   (0.70, 0.70, 0.70, 0.80)
  colorUpland    (0.65, 0.65, 0.65, 1.00)
  colorRock      (0.60, 0.60, 0.60, 1.00)
  colorSnow      (1.00, 1.00, 1.00, 1.00)
}
```

#### Blue ice

```
Palette {
  Class          "IceWorld"
  StyleRange     (0.00, 0.00)
  colorSea       (0.30, 0.25, 0.22, 0.00)
  colorShelf     (0.37, 0.31, 0.28, 0.00)
  colorBeach     (0.65, 0.86, 0.88, 0.20)
  colorDesert    (0.59, 0.76, 0.80, 0.50)
  colorLowland   (0.93, 0.95, 0.95, 0.80)
  colorUpland    (0.90, 0.98, 0.98, 1.00)
  colorRock      (0.60, 0.60, 0.60, 1.00)
  colorSnow      (1.00, 1.00, 1.00, 1.00)
}
```

#### Purple colors

```
Palette {
  Class          "IceWorld"
  StyleRange     (0.00, 0.00)
  colorSea       (0.30, 0.25, 0.22, 0.00)
  colorShelf     (0.37, 0.31, 0.28, 0.00)
  colorBeach     (0.82, 0.77, 0.81, 0.20)
  colorDesert    (0.64, 0.52, 0.56, 0.50)
  colorLowland   (0.53, 0.41, 0.44, 0.80)
  colorUpland    (0.56, 0.41, 0.45, 1.00)
  colorRock      (0.60, 0.60, 0.60, 1.00)
  colorSnow      (1.00, 1.00, 1.00, 1.00)
}
```

#### Orange impurities

```
Palette {
  Class          "IceWorld"
  StyleRange     (0.00, 0.00)
  colorSea       (0.30, 0.25, 0.22, 0.00)
  colorShelf     (0.37, 0.31, 0.28, 0.00)
  colorBeach     (0.98, 0.98, 0.96, 1.00)
  colorDesert    (0.73, 0.35, 0.14, 0.50)
  colorLowland   (0.82, 0.37, 0.17, 0.80)
  colorUpland    (0.98, 0.98, 0.96, 1.00)
  colorRock      (0.60, 0.60, 0.60, 1.00)
  colorSnow      (1.00, 1.00, 1.00, 1.00)
}
```

#### Pardo

```
Palette {
  Class          "IceWorld"
  StyleRange     (0.00, 0.00)
  colorSea       (0.30, 0.25, 0.22, 0.00)
  colorShelf     (0.37, 0.31, 0.28, 0.00)
  colorBeach     (0.78, 0.75, 0.64, 1.00)
  colorDesert    (0.51, 0.44, 0.34, 0.50)
  colorLowland   (0.63, 0.58, 0.45, 0.80)
  colorUpland    (0.91, 0.90, 0.75, 1.00)
  colorRock      (0.39, 0.39, 0.23, 1.00)
  colorSnow      (1.00, 1.00, 1.00, 1.00)
}
```

#### Ganymede 2

```
Palette {
  Class          "IceWorld"
  StyleRange     (0.00, 0.00)
  colorSea       (0.30, 0.25, 0.22, 0.00)
  colorShelf     (0.37, 0.31, 0.28, 0.00)
  colorBeach     (0.77, 0.70, 0.64, 1.00)
  colorDesert    (0.82, 0.75, 0.69, 0.50)
  colorLowland   (0.73, 0.70, 0.64, 0.80)
  colorUpland    (0.69, 0.65, 0.61, 1.00)
  colorRock      (0.53, 0.43, 0.37, 1.00)
  colorSnow      (1.00, 1.00, 1.00, 1.00)
}
```

#### Brown-grey colors

```
Palette {
  Class          "IceWorld"
  StyleRange     (0.00, 0.00)
  colorSea       (0.30, 0.25, 0.22, 0.00)
  colorShelf     (0.37, 0.31, 0.28, 0.00)
  colorBeach     (0.60, 0.56, 0.54, 1.00)
  colorDesert    (0.49, 0.36, 0.25, 0.50)
  colorLowland   (0.75, 0.69, 0.66, 0.80)
  colorUpland    (0.76, 0.74, 0.70, 1.00)
  colorRock      (0.25, 0.21, 0.15, 1.00)
  colorSnow      (1.00, 1.00, 1.00, 1.00)
}
```

#### Blue-grey

```
Palette {
  Class          "GasGiant"
  StyleRange     (0.00, 0.00)
  colorSea       (0.28, 0.26, 0.25, 1.00)
  colorShelf     (0.30, 0.28, 0.27, 1.00)
  colorBeach     (0.01, 0.01, 0.03, 1.00)
  colorDesert    (0.22, 0.30, 0.41, 1.00)
  colorLowland   (0.69, 0.61, 0.53, 1.00)
  colorUpland    (0.30, 0.29, 0.27, 1.00)
  colorRock      (0.41, 0.37, 0.36, 1.00)
  colorSnow      (0.61, 0.59, 0.70, 1.00)
}
```

#### Light colour

```
Palette {
  Class          "GasGiant"
  StyleRange     (0.00, 0.00)
  colorSea       (0.28, 0.26, 0.25, 1.00)
  colorShelf     (0.30, 0.28, 0.27, 1.00)
  colorBeach     (0.79, 0.75, 0.72, 1.00)
  colorDesert    (0.75, 0.73, 0.72, 1.00)
  colorLowland   (0.68, 0.67, 0.64, 1.00)
  colorUpland    (0.57, 0.59, 0.60, 1.00)
  colorRock      (0.55, 0.55, 0.56, 1.00)
  colorSnow      (0.69, 0.66, 0.62, 1.00)
}
```

#### Red-brown-grey colors

```
Palette {
  Class          "GasGiant"
  StyleRange     (0.00, 0.00)
  colorSea       (0.28, 0.26, 0.25, 1.00)
  colorShelf     (0.30, 0.28, 0.27, 1.00)
  colorBeach     (0.08, 0.04, 0.04, 1.00)
  colorDesert    (0.90, 0.42, 0.25, 1.00)
  colorLowland   (0.62, 0.11, 0.10, 1.00)
  colorUpland    (0.90, 0.42, 0.25, 1.00)
  colorRock      (0.34, 0.16, 0.09, 1.00)
  colorSnow      (0.69, 0.66, 0.62, 1.00)
}
```

#### Red-black-grey colors

```
Palette {
  Class          "GasGiant"
  StyleRange     (0.00, 0.00)
  colorSea       (0.28, 0.26, 0.25, 1.00)
  colorShelf     (0.30, 0.28, 0.27, 1.00)
  colorBeach     (0.08, 0.04, 0.04, 1.00)
  colorDesert    (0.08, 0.04, 0.04, 1.00)
  colorLowland   (0.62, 0.11, 0.10, 1.00)
  colorUpland    (0.08, 0.04, 0.04, 1.00)
  colorRock      (0.34, 0.16, 0.09, 1.00)
  colorSnow      (0.69, 0.66, 0.62, 1.00)
}
```

#### Light brown colors

```
Palette {
  Class          "GasGiant"
  StyleRange     (0.00, 0.00)
  colorSea       (0.84, 0.73, 0.57, 1.00)
  colorShelf     (0.85, 0.75, 0.60, 1.00)
  colorBeach     (0.34, 0.29, 0.20, 1.00)
  colorDesert    (0.46, 0.38, 0.27, 1.00)
  colorLowland   (0.56, 0.47, 0.32, 1.00)
  colorUpland    (0.58, 0.50, 0.36, 1.00)
  colorRock      (0.73, 0.63, 0.48, 1.00)
  colorSnow      (0.69, 0.66, 0.62, 1.00)
}
```

#### Grey colors

```
Palette {
  Class          "GasGiant"
  StyleRange     (0.00, 0.00)
  colorSea       (0.81, 0.81, 0.81, 1.00)
  colorShelf     (0.63, 0.65, 0.65, 1.00)
  colorBeach     (0.58, 0.56, 0.58, 1.00)
  colorDesert    (0.61, 0.61, 0.63, 1.00)
  colorLowland   (0.72, 0.72, 0.72, 1.00)
  colorUpland    (0.78, 0.78, 0.78, 1.00)
  colorRock      (0.54, 0.54, 0.56, 1.00)
  colorSnow      (0.69, 0.66, 0.62, 1.00)
}
```

#### Dark grey colors

```
Palette {
  Class          "GasGiant"
  StyleRange     (0.00, 0.00)
  colorSea       (0.30, 0.30, 0.30, 1.00)
  colorShelf     (0.30, 0.30, 0.30, 1.00)
  colorBeach     (0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 1.00)
  colorDesert    (0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 1.00)
  colorLowland   (0.30, 0.30, 0.30, 1.00)
  colorUpland    (0.80, 0.80, 0.80, 1.00)
  colorRock      (0.24, 0.24, 0.26, 1.00)
  colorSnow      (0.30, 0.30, 0.30, 1.00)
}
```

#### Dark grey with more white clouds

```
Palette {
  Class          "GasGiant"
  StyleRange     (0.00, 0.00)
  colorSea       (0.30, 0.30, 0.30, 1.00)
  colorShelf     (0.80, 0.80, 0.80, 1.00)
  colorBeach     (0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 1.00)
  colorDesert    (0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 1.00)
  colorLowland   (0.30, 0.30, 0.30, 1.00)
  colorUpland    (0.80, 0.80, 0.80, 1.00)
  colorRock      (0.24, 0.24, 0.26, 1.00)
  colorSnow      (0.30, 0.30, 0.30, 1.00)
}
Deserts:
```

#### Olivine mountains

```
Palette {
  Class          "Desert"
  StyleRange     (0.00, 0.00)
  colorSea       (0.69, 0.54, 0.42, 0.00)
  colorShelf     (0.64, 0.50, 0.37, 0.00)
  colorBeach     (0.86, 0.70, 0.50, 0.00)
  colorDesert    (0.75, 0.59, 0.42, 0.00)
  colorLowland   (0.63, 0.48, 0.35, 0.00)
  colorUpland    (0.38, 0.30, 0.20, 0.00)
  colorRock      (0.09, 0.12, 0.07, 0.00)
  colorSnow      (1.00, 1.00, 1.00, 1.00)
}
```

#### Red desert

```
Palette {
  Class          "Desert"
  StyleRange     (0.00, 0.00)
  colorSea       (0.69, 0.54, 0.42, 0.00)
  colorShelf     (0.64, 0.50, 0.37, 0.00)
  colorBeach     (0.81, 0.45, 0.32, 0.00)
  colorDesert    (0.61, 0.31, 0.21, 0.00)
  colorLowland   (0.76, 0.45, 0.32, 0.00)
  colorUpland    (0.96, 0.57, 0.39, 0.00)
  colorRock      (0.42, 0.24, 0.16, 0.00)
  colorSnow      (1.00, 1.00, 1.00, 1.00)
}
```

#### Cream and red dunes

```
Palette {
  Class          "Desert"
  StyleRange     (0.00, 0.00)
  colorSea       (0.69, 0.54, 0.42, 0.00)
  colorShelf     (0.64, 0.50, 0.37, 0.00)
  colorBeach     (0.80, 0.77, 0.51, 0.00)
  colorDesert    (0.88, 0.67, 0.48, 0.00)
  colorLowland   (0.80, 0.69, 0.49, 0.00)
  colorUpland    (0.99, 1.00, 0.75, 0.00)
  colorRock      (0.56, 0.50, 0.30, 0.00)
  colorSnow      (1.00, 1.00, 1.00, 1.00)
}
```

#### Arid badlands

```
Palette {
  Class          "Desert"
  StyleRange     (0.00, 0.00)
  colorSea       (0.69, 0.54, 0.42, 0.00)
  colorShelf     (0.64, 0.50, 0.37, 0.00)
  colorBeach     (0.69, 0.46, 0.35, 0.00)
  colorDesert    (0.43, 0.24, 0.18, 0.00)
  colorLowland   (0.49, 0.38, 0.39, 0.00)
  colorUpland    (0.90, 0.51, 0.33, 0.00)
  colorRock      (0.37, 0.25, 0.27, 0.00)
  colorSnow      (1.00, 1.00, 1.00, 1.00)
}
```

#### Red and yellow surface

```
Palette {
  Class          "Desert"
  StyleRange     (0.00, 0.00)
  colorSea       (0.69, 0.54, 0.42, 0.00)
  colorShelf     (0.64, 0.50, 0.37, 0.00)
  colorBeach     (0.51, 0.35, 0.27, 0.00)
  colorDesert    (0.74, 0.58, 0.36, 0.00)
  colorLowland   (0.65, 0.52, 0.27, 0.00)
  colorUpland    (0.67, 0.47, 0.32, 0.00)
  colorRock      (0.50, 0.34, 0.24, 0.00)
  colorSnow      (1.00, 1.00, 1.00, 1.00)
}
```

#### Light turquesa desert

```
Palette {
  Class          "Desert"
  StyleRange     (0.00, 0.00)
  colorSea       (0.69, 0.54, 0.42, 0.00)
  colorShelf     (0.64, 0.50, 0.37, 0.00)
  colorBeach     (0.41, 0.67, 0.63, 0.00)
  colorDesert    (0.26, 0.31, 0.23, 0.00)
  colorLowland   (0.49, 0.63, 0.49, 0.00)
  colorUpland    (0.38, 0.59, 0.50, 0.00)
  colorRock      (0.36, 0.39, 0.33, 0.00)
  colorSnow      (1.00, 1.00, 1.00, 1.00)
}
```

#### Contrast colors

```
Palette {
  Class          "Desert"
  StyleRange     (0.00, 0.00)
  colorSea       (0.69, 0.54, 0.42, 0.00)
  colorShelf     (0.64, 0.50, 0.37, 0.00)
  colorBeach     (0.51, 0.51, 0.49, 0.00)
  colorDesert    (0.19, 0.19, 0.22, 0.00)
  colorLowland   (0.55, 0.49, 0.46, 0.00)
  colorUpland    (0.49, 0.49, 0.47, 0.00)
  colorRock      (0.42, 0.41, 0.40, 0.00)
  colorSnow      (1.00, 1.00, 1.00, 1.00)
}
```

#### Butano

```
Palette {
  Class          "Desert"
  StyleRange     (0.00, 0.00)
  colorSea       (0.69, 0.54, 0.42, 0.00)
  colorShelf     (0.64, 0.50, 0.37, 0.00)
  colorBeach     (0.92, 0.56, 0.26, 0.00)
  colorDesert    (0.85, 0.50, 0.24, 0.00)
  colorLowland   (0.71, 0.47, 0.29, 0.00)
  colorUpland    (0.55, 0.40, 0.33, 0.00)
  colorRock      (0.51, 0.43, 0.40, 0.00)
  colorSnow      (1.00, 1.00, 1.00, 1.00)
}
```

Comment: Good to see that, if we ruin our current planet, we can always generate a new one : )

Comment: What the actual F? This is like everything and beyond for this topic. Impressed. I can't even right now.